# Spotify authorization_code

Tags: ruby, spotify, omniauth

I'm trying to allow my app to log into Spotify via their [Authorization Code Flow](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/#authorization_code_flow).  I am able to receive an authorization `code` from Spotify in the initial authorization step, but receive the following error when trying to get an access token:

`{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Invalid client"}`

My code is as follows:

```
# Callback from Spotify Authorization
get '/auth/spotify/callback' do
  session[:code] = params[:code]
  redirect to '/refresh'
end
```

Then, I am POSTing the following:

```
get '/refresh' do
  uri = URI('https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token')
  resp = Net::HTTP.post(uri,
    {
      "grant_type" => "authorization_code",
      "code" => session[:code].to_s,
      "redirect_uri" => "http://localhost:4567/auth/spotify/callback",
      "client_id" => client_id,
      "client_secret" => client_secret 
    }.to_json
  )
  "#{resp.body}"
end
```

Any help would be appreciated

EDIT: I've also tried to POST the same parameters above using PostMan, but receive the same error message

Comment: This looks like a pretty typical OAuth2 flow. You might want to consider using something like [oauth2](https://github.com/intridea/oauth2) for the sake of simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the Authorization header in your POST request.

Add the following key in your Net::HTTP.post options :

`{'Authorization' => 'Basic YOUR_AUTH_CODE' }`

EDIT :

This is in the docs under the ['Your application requests refresh and access tokens'](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/#authorization-code-flow) heading.

Comment: Yes, I've seen this. But there is also a snippet right below the `Authorzation` section that says you can include your non-base64 encoded id and secret inside the body.  Regardless, I tried your way and still receive the same error

Comment: Can you still try to add the Authorization Header and remove the client_id, secret_id keys ?

Comment: If I add a header, the error message changes to `{"error":"unsupported_grant_type","error_description":"grant_type must be client_credentials, authorization_code or refresh_token"}` SEE: https://gist.github.com/mindovermiles262/66ff2fc1da8c4c6220365f16845ca8ae

Comment: @Andy Can you also explicitly set the Content Type to application/json ? I read this in the docs : 'You should set Content-Type: header field for POST. If no Content-Type: field given, this method uses “application/x-www-form-urlencoded” by default.'

Comment: `{ 'Authorization' => auth, 'Content Type' => 'application/json' }` returns the unsupported grant type error

Comment: can you the 'Authorization:' string before the 'Basic' word, weird but in the docs it says that it must have this format `Authorization: Basic <base64 encoded client_id:client_secret>`

Also if the unsupported_grand_type keeps occurring it may be caused by a wrong shaped body

Comment: Moving the `Authorize` inside gives me a 415 Unexpected Status SEE: https://gist.github.com/mindovermiles262/442d6f3284e960faef891fe23ee51d00

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question:

I didn't need to make the request since the gem I was using, `'omniauth-spotify'`, could return the access token to me in `request.env['omniauth.auth'].credentials.token`

I was also creating the POST request incorrectly.  The example below is the correct way to make a POST and obtain a new token from a `refresh_token` (provided in the above `.credentials` hash)

```
# Get new access token from refresh token
# session[:creds] = request.env['omniauth.auth'].credentials

get '/refresh' do
  refresh_token = session[:creds].refresh_token
  auth = "Basic " + Base64.strict_encode64("#{client_id}:#{client_secret}")
  uri = URI.parse('https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token')
  request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri)
  request["Authorization"] = auth
  request.set_form_data(
    "grant_type" => "refresh_token",
    "refresh_token" => refresh_token,
  )

  req_options = {
    use_ssl: uri.scheme == "https",
  }

  response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, req_options) do |http|
    http.request(request)
  end

  "#{response.code}" # > 200 OK

end
```